# Editing object relations in MVC models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have a problem with a related object in MVC 5.2.3, Entity Framework 6. I can not update the relation to another object in my model. There is an AudiogramModel with a property InstrumentModel and int ID inherited from BaseModel.

```
public class AudiogramModel : BaseModel
{
    //Other properties...

    public InstrumentModel Instrument { get; set; }
}
```

The instrument model is defined as follows:

```
public class InstrumentModel : BaseModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and just like Audiogram inherits a key - ID from BaseModel.

In the controller AudiogramController the method Edit is supposed to receive whole AudiogramModel with InstrumentModel inside a view model AudiogramCreateEditViewModel, and then to save the edited AudiogramModel with InstrumentModel inside.

The view model is defined as:

```
public class AudiogramCreateEditViewModel
{
    public AudiogramModel Audiogram { get; set; }
    public int[] Frequencies { get; set; }
    public List<InstrumentModel> Instruments { get; set; }
}
```

While the Frequencies and the List aren't important(for they are used to pass those models to the Edit view), there is the Audiogram property in it, which interests me.

```
    public ActionResult Edit(AudiogramCreateEditViewModel audiogramEdit)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (audiogramEdit.Audiogram.IsMusician == true)
            {
                //db is the standard context of the controller
                InstrumentModel instrument = db.InstrumentModels.FirstOrDefault<InstrumentModel>(x => x.Name == audiogramEdit.Audiogram.Instrument.Name);
                if (instrument == null)
                {
                    db.InstrumentModels.Add(audiogramEdit.Audiogram.Instrument);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                else
                {
                    audiogramEdit.Audiogram.Instrument = instrument;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                audiogramEdit.Audiogram.Instrument = null;
            }
            db.AudiogramModels.Attach(audiogramEdit.Audiogram);
            db.Entry(audiogramEdit.Audiogram).State = EntityState.Modified;
            var a = db.ChangeTracker.Entries();
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index"); 
  }
```

}

The model passes the validation and seems ok. The thing is, although the Audiogram model is correct and may be saved with db.AudiogramModels.Add(audiogramEdit.Audiogram); there is no way to update it. What is more, without the line db.AudiogramModels.Attach(audiogramEdit.Audiogram); the Entity tracker doesn't even track the audiogramEdit.Audiogram. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something you can't exactly "fix". Keep in mind what the code is really doing. In your Get action you're looking up an `AudiogramCreateEditViewModel`, serializing it (and all of its properties), and sending it over to the client to be rendered on their web page. The client re-serializes it and sends it back to your Edit method. The server deserializes it and gives you *new* a `AudiogramCreateEditViewModel` instance.

There's no way for EntityFramework to know about this new instance that MVC created for you. If you want to do an update, you have to tell the context about it. The simplest way to do that is to fetch the object from the context again and copy the properties from your ViewModel.

You may also notice that if you're copying properties manually, you don't really have to have an instance of AudiogramModel on your ViewModel at all. You can create a simpler class which contains only the properties you expect to edit the view and an Id you can use to look up the domain model with. In the long run, this simplifies your UI layer quite a bit.

Comment: And what about nulling existing relations?
I have a foreign key in the AudiogramModels database - Instrument_ID. It surely can be set null.
I have returned a tracked AudiogramModel TrackedAudiogram from the database and assigned all the values. However, neither saving it with Instrument = null nor with a new Instrument, where Instrument.ID = 0 and Instrument.Name = null.

It doesn't change to null. The only way I found is creating an Instrument with Name=null, to which every AudiogramModel without an Instrument assigned points.

Is it the problem with ID which is int and not "int?"?

Comment: You can null the foreign key by setting Instrument = null. There must be something else going on with the tracking or database mappings. To test, try looking up the objevt from the database, set the field to null, then save immediately.